# Possible memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I have the following code:

```
void customHandleException  (_EXCEPTION_POINTERS* ExceptionInfo)
{
      char* x = (char*)ExceptionInfo->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionInformation[0];
      delete[] x;
}


void foo()
{
   char* x = new char[ 256 ];
   ULONG_PTR* args = new ULONG_PTR[1];
   args[0] = (long)x;
   RaiseException(EXCEPTION_CODE,0,1,args);
}
```

Leaving all else aside, `char* x` from `customHandleException()` will point to the char array allocated in `foo()`. Will this cause a memory leak or will the delete work?

Comment: Underscore-capital names are not permitted in user code; they're reserved for the compiler and the standard library.

Comment: No, that's a good comment.  If it was an answer _then_ it would be missing the point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be using `delete[]`. Memory allocated with `new[]` **MUST** be deallocated with `delete[]`.

Reference:

**C++03 Standard: § 3.7.4.2-3**

> If a deallocation function terminates by throwing an exception, the behavior is undefined. The value of the first argument supplied to a deallocation function may be a null pointer value; if so, and if the deallocation function is one supplied in the standard library, the call has no effect. Otherwise, the value supplied
>   to operator `delete(void*)` in the standard library shall be one of the values returned by a previous invocation of either operator `new(std::size_t)` or `operator new(std::size_t, const std::nothrow_-t&)` in the standard library, **and the value supplied to operator `delete[](void*)` in the standard library shall be one of the values returned by a previous invocation of either `operator new[](std::size_t)` or
>   `operator new[](std::size_t, const std::nothrow_t&)` in the standard library.**

Comment: Other than that, will there be a memory leak? That was a typo :)

Comment: @Luchian: As long as you call `delete[]` with the same address returned by `new[]`, there won't be any leak.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore: Okay, if it was a typo your code was okay from the very beginning.